# Making a custom button in Qt5 with paintEvent

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I want to make a custom button which looks the same on every platform without inheriting QPushButton or QAbstractButton but QWidget instead. This button should contain a pixmap as icon and a text plus an optional subtitle. I got that working so far but the problem is the widget width. The widget itself gets clipped at some width.

My question is how the parent widget knows what is the new size of the widget when I painted a lot of stuff with the painter? The new size could be anything depending on the text or pixmap.

**Edit 1**

The size hint gives an estimate about the required size

```
QSize Button::sizeHint() const {
    QFont nameFont(font());
    QFont descriptionFont(font());
    QFontMetrics nameFontMetric(nameFont);
    QFontMetrics descriptionFontMetric(descriptionFont);
    nameFont.setBold(true);

    QSize result(0, 0);
    result.setWidth(getPixmap().width() + 5
            + nameFontMetric.horizontalAdvance(' ')
            + qMax(descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->description).width(), nameFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->name).width()));
    result.setHeight(qMax(getPixmap().height(),
            nameFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->name).height() + descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->description).height()));

    return result;
}
```

The paint method is called from within the paintEvent method where a painter is created with QPainter(this)

```
void Button::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QRect drawingRect;

    QFont nameFont(painter->font());
    QFont descriptionFont(painter->font());
    nameFont.setBold(true);
    descriptionFont.setPointSize(nameFont.pointSize() / 1.5);

    QFontMetrics nameFontMetric(nameFont, painter->device());
    QFontMetrics descriptionFontMetric(descriptionFont, painter->device());

    auto nameFontRectInitial = nameFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->name + " ");
    auto nameFontRect = nameFontMetric.boundingRect(nameFontRectInitial, 0, m_ptr->name + " ");

    auto descriptionFontRectInitial = descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->description + " ");
    auto descriptionFontRect = descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(descriptionFontRectInitial, 0, m_ptr->description + " ");

    // Get rect of widget so far
    auto r = rect();

    auto labelRect       = r;
    auto descriptionRect = r;

    labelRect       = labelRect.translated(getPixmap().width() + 5, 0);
    descriptionRect = descriptionRect.translated(getPixmap().width() + 5, 0);

    labelRect.setSize(nameFontRect.size());
    descriptionRect.setSize(descriptionFontRect.size());

    descriptionRect.translate(0, labelRect.height());

    //setFixedSize((labelRect | descriptionRect).size());
    drawingRect = labelRect | descriptionRect | getPixmap().rect();
    drawingRect.adjust(0,0,5,0);
    resize(drawingRect.size());

    // Draw background
    painter->fillRect(drawingRect, palette().color(QPalette::Button));

    // Draw name
    painter->setFont(nameFont);
    painter->setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Text));
    painter->drawText(labelRect, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::TextSingleLine, m_ptr->name);

    // Draw description
    painter->setFont(descriptionFont);
    painter->setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Text));
    painter->drawText(descriptionRect, Qt::AlignTop, m_ptr->description);

    // Draw border
    painter->setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Midlight));
    painter->drawRect(drawingRect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));

    painter->drawPixmap(m_ptr->pixmapOrigin, m_ptr->pixmap);
```

With this method I got it working so far but another problem is sizing within a layout where I want to stretch that widget so that all widgets in a row have the same width. This seems not the case and I don't know how to do that.

**Edit 2:**

I got that working by using updateGeometry() which tells the layout system that the size hint changed (Thats how I understand the documentation). The downside of that is I have to keep the size internally and check if it changed inside the paintEvent.

```
void Button::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QRect drawingRect;

    QFont nameFont(painter->font());
    QFont descriptionFont(painter->font());
    nameFont.setBold(true);
    descriptionFont.setPointSize(nameFont.pointSize() / 1.5);

    QFontMetrics nameFontMetric(nameFont, painter->device());
    QFontMetrics descriptionFontMetric(descriptionFont, painter->device());

    auto nameFontRectInitial = nameFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->name + " ");
    auto nameFontRect = nameFontMetric.boundingRect(nameFontRectInitial, 0, m_ptr->name + " ");

    auto descriptionFontRectInitial = descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->description + " ");
    auto descriptionFontRect = descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(descriptionFontRectInitial, 0, m_ptr->description + " ");

    // Get rect of widget so far
    auto r = rect();

    auto labelRect       = r;
    auto descriptionRect = r;

    labelRect       = labelRect.translated(getPixmap().width() + 5, 0);
    descriptionRect = descriptionRect.translated(getPixmap().width() + 5, 0);

    labelRect.setSize(nameFontRect.size());
    descriptionRect.setSize(descriptionFontRect.size());

    descriptionRect.translate(0, labelRect.height());

    drawingRect = labelRect | descriptionRect | getPixmap().rect();
    drawingRect.adjust(0,0,5,0);

    if(drawingRect.width() != m_ptr->w || drawingRect.height() != m_ptr->h) {
        m_ptr->w = drawingRect.width();
        m_ptr->h = drawingRect.height();
        updateGeometry();
    }

    // Draw background
    painter->fillRect(r, palette().color(QPalette::Button));

    // Draw name
    painter->setFont(nameFont);
    painter->setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Text));
    painter->drawText(labelRect, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::TextSingleLine, m_ptr->name);

    // Draw description
    painter->setFont(descriptionFont);
    painter->setPen(palette().color(QPalette::Text));
    painter->drawText(descriptionRect, Qt::AlignTop, m_ptr->description);

}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried thus far (preferably as a [mcve]) and have a look at [`QWidget::sizeHint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) as well as [`QWidget::sizePolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop).

Answer (score 0):

Layout uses `sizeHint` to know how much space widget needs, and distributes all extra space according to stretch factor, but as long as you buttons returns different `sizeHints` (that depends on text they contain) even with the same stretch factor they end up with different width. So easiest way to achieve same width for buttons in same row is to make them return same `sizeHint`.

For example you can create helper function `makeSameWidth` that calculates maximum button width for group of buttons and forces them to return this width in `sizeHint`. You can apply that function after aplying layout to the widget.

```
void makeSameWidth(QList<Button*> buttons, QLayout* layout) {
  int width = 0;
  for(Button* button: buttons) {
      width = qMax(button.sizeHint().width(), width);
  }
  for(Button* button: buttons) {
      button->setSizeHintWidth(width);
  }
  layout->invalidate();
}

class Button {
...

   Button (...) : m_width(-1) ...

   void setSizeHintWidth(int width) {
      m_width = width;
   }

   int m_width;
}

QSize Button::sizeHint() const {
   ...
   int width;
   if (m_width < 0) {
     width = getPixmap().width() + 5
            + nameFontMetric.horizontalAdvance(' ')
            + qMax(descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->description).width(), nameFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->name).width());
   } else {
     width = m_width;
   }
   int height = qMax(getPixmap().height(),
            nameFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->name).height() + descriptionFontMetric.boundingRect(m_ptr->description).height());
   return QSizeHint(width, heigth);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    makeSameWidth({ui->button1, ui->button2, ui->button3}, ui->buttonsLayout);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got that working so far by using updateGeometry() I don't know if that is the intended way Qt should be informed about a size change of a widget. I think the makeSameWidth would require me to know each of the buttons but that is what I want to avoid.